# Filter order view by products id in table order woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am facing difficulties regarding filtering orders on the shop order page. Is there anyone who can help me with resolving this issue?,
and I have created a new menu to display the 'Pending Concierge' order table, intending to show orders with a pending status. The issue I am currently facing is that when I add a new product ID for filtering and displaying in the order table.
The code before

```
 if (current_user_can('dashboard_concierge')) {
        $product_ids = array(25491);
```

and after I added the new product ID is as follows:

```
 if (current_user_can('dashboard_concierge')) {
        $product_ids = array(25491,1779,25485);
```

it results in an error, and no results are displayed – the value becomes zero.
and here the image result
[image]

and this full code

```
// Fungsi untuk memodifikasi tautan subsubsub
function modify_subsubsub_actions($subsubsub) {
    global $wpdb;

    if (current_user_can('dashboard_concierge')) {
        $product_ids = array(25491,1779,25485); // 

        // Generate placeholders for product IDs in the SQL query
        $placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($product_ids), '%d'));

        $completed_menu_label = sprintf(__('Completed (%d Orders)', 'textdomain'), 0);
        $completed_menu_url = add_query_arg(
            array(
                'post_status' => 'wc-completed',
                'post_type' => 'shop_order',
                'product_ids' => implode(',', $product_ids),
                'concierge_menu' => 'completed',
            ),
            admin_url('edit.php')
        );

        $pending_menu_label = sprintf(__('Pending Concierge (%d Orders)', 'textdomain'), 0);
        $pending_menu_url = add_query_arg(
            array(
                'post_status' => 'wc-pending',
                'post_type' => 'shop_order',
                'product_ids' => implode(',', $product_ids),
                'concierge_menu' => 'pending',
            ),
            admin_url('edit.php')
        );

       
        $completed_orders_count = count(get_orders_ids_by_product_id_filter($product_ids, array('wc-completed')));

        $completed_menu_label = sprintf(__('Completed (%d Orders)', 'textdomain'), $completed_orders_count);
        $subsubsub = array_slice($subsubsub, 0, 2, true) +
            array('completed' => '<a href="#" data-url="' . esc_url($completed_menu_url) . '" class="concierge-link">' . $completed_menu_label . '</a>') +
            array_slice($subsubsub, 2, null, true);

        $pending_orders_count = count(get_orders_ids_by_product_id_filter($product_ids, array('wc-pending')));

        $pending_menu_label = sprintf(__('Pending Concierge (%d Orders)', 'textdomain'), $pending_orders_count);
        $subsubsub = array_slice($subsubsub, 0, 2, true) +
            array('pending_payment' => '<a href="#" data-url="' . esc_url($pending_menu_url) . '" class="concierge-link">' . $pending_menu_label . '</a>') +
            array_slice($subsubsub, 2, null, true);

        // skcript JavaScript for the link
        add_action('admin_footer', function () {
            ?>
            <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                    // Menangani klik pada tautan dengan class 'concierge-link'
                    $('.concierge-link').on('click', function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault(); // Mencegah navigasi default
                        window.location.href = $(this).data('url'); // M
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        });

        // unset menu
        unset($subsubsub['all']);
        unset($subsubsub['wc-completed']);
       unset($subsubsub['wc-pending']);
    }

    return $subsubsub;
}

add_filter('views_edit-shop_order', 'modify_subsubsub_actions');

// Function to get product by id
function get_orders_ids_by_product_id_filter($product_ids, $order_status = array('wc-completed','wc-pending')) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Generate placeholders for product IDs in the SQL query
    $placeholders = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($product_ids), '%d'));

    // Query ID for order with another product id
    $results = $wpdb->get_col(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT DISTINCT order_items.order_id
            FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as order_items
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as order_item_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_item_meta.order_item_id
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_items.order_id = posts.ID
            WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
            AND posts.post_status IN ( '" . implode( "','", $order_status ) . "' )
            AND order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
            AND order_item_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
            AND CAST(order_item_meta.meta_value AS SIGNED) IN ($placeholders)
            GROUP BY order_items.order_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT order_item_meta.meta_value) = " . count($product_ids),
            ...$product_ids
        )
    );

    return $results;
}

// Filter for query
function apply_product_filter_to_order_query($query) {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'shop_order' && isset($_GET['product_ids'])) {
        $product_ids = array_map('intval', explode(',', $_GET['product_ids']));
        $order_ids = get_orders_ids_by_product_id_filter($product_ids);

        if (!empty($order_ids)) {
            $query->query_vars['post__in'] = $order_ids;
        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'apply_product_filter_to_order_query');
```

i try change the code but no luck